# How to create a 2D plane with arbitrary shape?

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

I am trying to 2D mesh of a logo (specifically [this](https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/middle/344-3444076_arch-linux-logo-png-clipart.png)). I want to make this into a 2D mesh that I could extrude into a 3D mesh later.

I have tried two approaches for this:

1. I added a bezier curve, deleted it in edit mode and then drew edges of the image by extruding the points. I then convert the curve into a mesh. The issue I face here is that there are too many vertices in the generated image, making it difficult for me to fill the mesh.
2. Using a plane, I positioned it on one end of the image and then extruded and scaled the edges to fit the image. The issue here is that by this approach, the curves are not as smooth as I would like. Not to mention that extruding and scaling edges is somewhat tedious.

So, I want to know if there is another (possibly easier) way to do this?

I am new to Blender, so apologies if this has been answered before but I was not sure what to search.

Comment: See if [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12YuQj48sr0) video helps.

Comment: "*I added a bezier curve, then convert the curve into a mesh. The issue I face here is that there are too many vertices in the generated image, making it difficult for me to fill the mesh.*" You are struggling with a self imposed issue. Why did you convert to mesh? You had a easily fillable bezier curve then intentionally converted into a mesh that can't be filled

Comment: The reason for that was that I was unable to close the Bezier curve into a loop (I am really a noob, sorry about that). So I converted into a mesh and extruded one end and snapped it to the start of the curve.

Comment: @JohnEason Wow, the method in the video is pretty straightforward. Though I am curious how did the curves get filled after importing the SVG?

Comment: It does work well if you experiment a bit. Create the SVG with a single colour then import into Blender and delete the material so that it's not black. Then convert it to a mesh and, as @Moonboots suggests, select all in Edit mode and X > Limited Dissolve. Setting the Max Angle in the bottom left dialog to around 1.2degrees seems to give the best result for your image.

Answer (score 3):

You can simplfy your mesh with <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve*. That said you can convert your bitmap image to mesh:

- import it as *Image > Reference*
- in the header menu > *Object > Convert > Trace Image to Grease Pencil*
- Select the new object it creates (the black one) and right click > *Convert to > Bezier Curve*
- Select the new object it creates (the hollow one) and right click > *Convert to > Mesh*
- Go in *Edit* mode, select all and <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve* in order to simplify the mesh, set the good value in the *Operator* box on the bottom left of your 3D view
- Fill with <kbd>F</kbd>